# How to combine a summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, summation

Is there a way to combine this into one summation or is it not possible:

$$\sum_{a=0}^A\sum_{b=1}^B f(a,b) + \sum_{a=1}^A\sum_{b=0}^B f(a,b)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Note that every $f(a,b)$ with $a\gt 0$ and $b \gt 0$ is part of both summations.  But $f(0,b)$ and $f(a,0)$ are only represented once, and $f(0,0)$ doesn't contribute at all.  This occurs often with summations-you need to think about getting every term once and only once in your rewrite.

Comment: I tried that (combining everything twice and then subtracting out the 0,0 case) but nothing I try is working

Comment: @user1947180:  I said some terms come in only once.  Maybe if you show your work we can find the problem.

Comment: Is the only way to simplify it the sum from a=1 and b=1 and then add on the sums assuming a=0 and then when b=0?

Comment: @user1947180:  only is a difficult word.  That approach works.  In some cases, there might be another.  You have found the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle), which is an extremely useful technique.

Comment: Is there a "cleaner" way to simplify the expression rather than expressing it as a three-part sum?

Comment: @user1947180:  Not that I know in general.  There may be features of $f(a,b)$ that allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Ross Millikan's suggestion,

$\begin{align}
\sum_{a=0}^A\sum_{b=1}^B f(a,b) + \sum_{a=1}^A\sum_{b=0}^B f(a,b)
&=\sum_{b=1}^B f(0,b)+\sum_{a=1}^A\sum_{b=1}^B f(a,b)
 + \sum_{a=1}^A f(a,0) +\sum_{a=1}^A\sum_{b=1}^B f(a,b)\\
&=\sum_{b=1}^B f(0,b)+ \sum_{a=1}^A f(a,0)
+2\sum_{a=1}^A\sum_{b=1}^B f(a,b)\\
\end{align}
$

Most of the result can be combined into
$2$ times the double summation,
but the two single summations
cannot be combined
unless you know something more
about $f$, $A$, and $B$.